# Broken profile picture

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar

The profile picture seems to be broken for some users. For example, for [user Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8120962/paul).

[image: Paul]

When I go to the [picture's link](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b7e12da9752ec88573c53161ee4fbe5f?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1), I see this:

[image: Profile picture]

Comment: Shows up fine for me.

Comment: Hmm.. Broken CDN?

Comment: Now I see it alright :/

Comment: Odd. Maybe you should see about filing a bug report with Gravatar. It seems like that's their problem, not SO's.

Comment: Just another problem with Gravatar causing problems on our site. Here's to hoping it gets ditched.